# All values are null when adding Arm64 Support

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8, arm64

I have been receiving the same warning when updating my application to the store which is mentioning that my application require to add the arm64 architecture before June.

When i tried to add the arm64 architecture in my last update, the application crashed with the store. The same thing happened when i tried to build it in release mode in edit scheme.

After debugging i noticed that all my values are nil, even when reading from NSUserDefaults will return nil values.

What should i do to solve this issue to be able to update my application later on? why all values are returning nil when adding arm64 architecture?

Thank you for your help.
Regards

Comment: That's not enough information.

Comment: How exactly did you add the arm64 support? Did you select "Standard architectures" from Build Settings - Architectures? Could you elaborate this: "crashed with the store".

Comment: @Tapani In the build settings, the  Build Settings Architecture are $(ARCHS_STANDARD) and in Valid architecture were armv7 and armv7s. I added arm64 to them